# How to fill cell-network partition matrix of a function?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm trying to understand a paper (Tandem Networks of Universal Cells, Butler, 1978 [1](https://doi.org/10.1109/TC.1978.1675199)), but I can't make it past the first paragraph:

> Consider the $x_l … x_{k - 1} | x_k$ partition matrix of a function $f(
> x_1, x_2, …, x_k)$, as shown in Fig. 1, where $C_0$ and $C_1$
> represent the $x_k = 0$ and $x_k = 1$ columns, respectively. Let $0$
> and $1$ represent the columns of all 0's and all 1's, respectively.
> Let $X$ denote a column with at least one 0 and at least one 1,
> and $\overline{X}$ its complement. The concatenation of two columns
> will represent a complete partition matrix. Thus, for example,
> $01$ represents $f(x_1, x_2, …, x_k) = x_k$ and $XX$ represents a
> function independent of $x_k$, but dependent on at least one of
> the remaining variables.

[image]

I'm trying to build something like a [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map), but the result I'm getting doesn't make sense.

For example, here's what I made from $f = x_1 \times x_2 \times x_3$ (with digital logic "&" for boolean times):

[image]

The first column ($C_0$) I would call $0$, from the author's definition, but the second column ($C_1$) doesn't seem to be a $0$, $1$, or $X$. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close.

I don't think that's what they intended as the partition matrix.  Instead, I think they intended the following matrix:

```
         x3
x1 x2 \  0 1
       -----
 0  0  | 0 0
 0  1  | 0 0
 1  0  | 0 0
 1  1  | 0 1
```

That's slightly different from what you have written.  In particular, the partition matrix will have $2^{k-1}$ rows and 2 columns.

It's best to think of the first sentence as one paragraph, and the remaining sentences as a second disconnected paragraph that is trying to explain a taxonomy for classifying a column of this matrix.  The author is proposing to classify every column into one of three types: all-zeros, all-ones, or contains both a 0 and a 1.  The paper represents an all-zeros column by 0, an all-ones column by 1, and the third case by X.  Thus, X is used to represent any column that contains at least one 0 and at least 1, i.e., any column that is not all-zeros and not all-ones.

By this classification, the partition matrix above would be of the form 0X: the first column is all-zeros (type 0), and the second column is type X.